# How to setup a "Schedule Reminder" to trigger on a regular interval that sends an email to a "Smart group"

Tags: smartgroups, scheduled-reminders

I have a smart group and would like to send an email to all those contacts on a regular interval. For example, every Sunday at 10am. How can I set this up please?  I have tried but cant seems to figure it out...

Comment: What would be the message?

Comment: @Pradeep Nayak the idea is to update a specific message template with some text updates on a regular intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the email content will include text and contact tokens than I would suggest  to create mailings and use [civicrm recurring mail](https://github.com/3sd/civicrm-recurring-mail) extension to setup as recurring.

Comment: Doesn't this statement effectively mean this won't function as a 'smart' mailing? "This means that any contacts that are added or removed to your groups in the time between when you hit the submit button and the date it is scheduled to go out will not receive your mailing"

Comment: I assumed the recipients are calculated just before the mailing job is processed may be I am wrong

Comment: I think might need this other extension as well to recalculate recipients: https://github.com/3sd/civicrm-recalculate-recipients

Comment: Are these extensions compatible with CiviCRM 5.x ?

Comment: Yes should be...

Comment: @PradeepNayak I have noticed if I change the content of message template after sending the master email, civi sends message the way it was created initially. is there a way to fix it so that the email would be sent dynamically as per the updated message template at a current time?